# Did Paul advised the Corinthians that it is better not to marry because the appointed time has grown very short?

Tags: 1-corinthians, marriage

> Yet those who marry will have worldly troubles, and I would spare you
>   that.  This is what I mean, brothers: the appointed time has grown
>   very short. From now on, let those who have wives live as though they
>   had none... (1 Cor 7:28, 29 ESV)

There is much benefit in raising children, one being that we have someone to take care of us when we get old.  Did Paul overlook this need of the elderly because of his belief that the coming of the Lord is imminent and that the Corinthians may not reach old age anyway?

My concern is on the practical application of Paul's advice.  Not getting married is a pivotal decision, and Paul's advice is one that speaks directly on the matter.

Comment: It is clear that Paul was not against marriage but he wrote it is better not to marry.

Comment: The question now seems to me to be confused: the title question is about non-marrying in the last days; the discussion of the question is about raising children. So -- either the question is a duplicate, or it is unanswerable: the "ethical" question makes no sense based on the premise of non-marriage in the eschaton.

Comment: Indeed I have not made the connection from marriage to raising children.  One of the purposes of getting into marriage is to raise children.

Answer (score 0):

"Because of the present crisis, I think that it is good for a man to remain as he is." The advise is based on the "present crisis..."
As is obvious from Paul's life (See 2 Corinthians 11, 12), persecution was a reality.  When you are married, the problem grows.  To an unmarried man/woman, when the question is raised to denounce Christ or else... the answer is really simple: Go ahead, kill me, I'm good.
When there is a spouse, and the spouse is threatened to be killed unless the partner renounces Christ, now the question becomes much more difficult.  And if the couple has kids, the problem becomes even more pressing.
The persecution would only become more oppressive after the days of Paul, hence "the time is short."

Unfortunately, the Catholic Church has taken this statement totally out of it's historical context, and made in binding in a way Scripture never did.